# Will Apple reject my iPhone application because of increasing memory usage?

Tags: iphone

I have an application with multiple views. It works pretty fine without any leaks or crashes. But when you run using performance tool for leaks, I see when I switch through multiple views and comeback to home screen, my overall size of the application gets increased. Like if its 1.53MB after visiting 4-5 different views and getting back to screen increases the consumption to 1.58MB or less but definitely greater than 1.53MB.
I tried resolving this issue but not able to figure out where I am going wrong since there are no memory leaks.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Will apple reject my application on this basis?

Comment: perhaps a parallel question on SO concerning just the memory leaks / growing memory might be a better issue to address here.

Comment: You should rename this question to: "Am I going to win at poker tonight?".  Getting your app approved is often luck =)

Comment: @jonnii: I was tempted to rename the question like that after reading your comment :)

Comment: Poker, with a 96% chance of winning, more if you're a halfway decent programmer.

Comment: Be aware that the Object Allocations instrument doesn't give the full picture as to your application's memory usage.  You'll also want to check the Memory Monitor instrument on the device itself to see if you're getting into dangerous territory.  For leaking UIViews, there will be a significant difference in these measurements.

Answer (score 1):

I would go back and forth between the screens many many many many times (at least one hundred times).  If the memory continues to grow (linearly) during that time, you have a problem.  If the memory stabilizes, you might be okay.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely keep trying to fix you memory leaks.  But if it's small, I doubt Apple will notice it.  I mean, their own apps leak some too.  You could get rejected for it, sure.  But realistically, leaking a few bytes here and there shouldn't prevent an approval by itself.

(Source, 2 apps approved, one with the same issue, a tiny little memory leak I couldn't track down.  I submitted it and was approved.  Shortly after, I found and fixed it and released it as part of an update).

Comment: Well There are no leaks, like I can see any red pyramid for the leaks. But only memory consumption like Object Allocation is increasing.

Comment: I had this problem with some web service calls.  Turns out that I was leaking a tiny little bit with every web service call.  It's never been a problem, but I did fix it...  I would never say "release it with known memory leaks", but, well...  I'm just saying that it won't be the only app in the app store with memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

If an application has an increasing memory footprint on a known stable state for example named A after going into and coming back from state B which should have no persistent affect on state A and there is no memory leaks this problem called (as much as I know) the lingering memory.

Checklist to be sure if you have lingering memory problem:

- App has no memory leaks, or no memory leaks on non-system code when profiled by Instruments.
- State A and State B are individually stable states, like in state-machine.
  State B has no permanent affect on State A, or it's memory. State A could be a gateway, a menu to another states like State B or State C. But Child states has no or limited info about state A and makes no change about State A.
- On loop state changes starts and ends with root state for example A->B->A, A->C->A, A->B->C->A; you encounter increasing memory usage on State A. Memory usage on other child states are not important.

To spot and solve this problem profile your app with instruments. But instead of monitoring leaks, you should monitor allocations and total memory. Every time your app gets to State A, including start, take a memory snapshot. (There is a button for that :D) After snapshot go to State B, State C and use your application as it suppose to. After coming back to root state, in this example State A, take another snapshot. Instruments will show you memory allocations and difference delta in total memory between snapshots. It will also give information about for which object the memory had allocated and when if possible. If it was your code you probably will see the type of class and allocation point. Instruments can not help you about when the object should have been released but when you got the lingering object or memory, figuring out the deallocation point should be much easier.

BUT! Do not forget:
OS and Framework codes could have leaks and lingering memory problems like every OS. If you are sure that it is not your code leaking or lingering in the memory the everything is fine. That was the case in my app and it got approved(App: Tusudoku). System function often use additional memory if there is available, but they immediately release it when received memory warning. Although devices has limited memory, it is a waste if still not used, and using memory does not make memory chip to use measurably increased electrical current. Using memory to the limits for performance and immediately releasing it when someone definitely needs it, is best possible practice. These cache memories does not tend to be grove over time linearly but you should force memory warning every time app gets to root state, in this example State A. So this way you will be sure any cache memory allocated by system or frameworks will be deallocated, then you take the snapshot.

Most of the apps on the App Store® has memory leaks and other memory problems. The question is how this affect user. Non-linear lingering memory with rapidly dropping acceleration on increase velocity generally won't be a reason for rejection. Calculated the memory usage as 15MB for a perfect working app but if it worked, no problem, say that it will reach 20MB limit max ever and you are good to go. So you later fix your memory problems. Bu if your application has a linear or worse increasing memory usage and can not release that memories when needed, that will be a critical problem.

For more information about memory usage please consider reading official documentation and watching WWDC videos(That's where I learned all about memory fixes using Instruments).

Answer (score 0):

There is no set in stone answer.

On the one hand is the fact that your application may have an obscure memory leak would be enough to reject it according to the posted policies.

On the other hand documents submitted to the FCC by Apple (in the AT&T+Apple vs. Google monopoly fight) give enough detail to work out just how much goes into reviewing an app - unless Apple lied the average app is reviewed by 2 people, and each of them spends around 5 minutes and 38 seconds (assuming Apple doesn't give breaks) to determine if your app passes or fails.

So the answer largely depends on if this memory leak can be discovered in the first 5 minutes of examination by some of the most overworked testers in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIImageViews in your views, then part of the extra memory could be the caching that it does.  See [here](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/).

Sometimes when we load views, and then switch to another, we leave the view around.  For example, if you have a rootviewcontroller that has all the views as retained properties.  Normally when you remove a subview, it is released, but not if you have it retained in your viewcontoller.  As yu can see, that would add up to memory consumed, but not freed.  It's not a leak, except that it gets released only when you release or remove the rootviewcontroller.

You could try to go through and find places where memory is tied up like this, or you could justify it based on the added speed of going through views without having to wait for them to reload.

In summary, it is good to know why your views and other objects consume and hold on to memory, but you may find that all those uses are justified, and you want to keep things that way.  Having said that, I don't think Apple will be rejecting our app for decisions like this.  If your app crashes because of memory usage, then that would get it rejected.

Comment: Yes I am using image animation and using UIImage imageNamed, so is that the issue, becoz I need those images most of the time and I cant use the strategy mentioned in the link u gave.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing very typical memory usage.

If your app runs out of memory and crashes while they're testing it, they will reject it.  Beyond that, you're fine.